# Почему gps видит изменение местоположения, а интернет нет?

Tags: android

Есть код для android, который определяет местоположение при помощи google-play-services. Код работает и местоположение выводится с заданным интервалом, но только когда включен gps, когда включен свой интернет - местоположение не находится. Как можно это исправить?

**MainActivity:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

public void onStart(View v) {
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

public void onStop(View v) {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

public synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("myLogs", "onConnected");
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    Log.d("myLogs", "onConnectionFailed");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    Log.d("myLogs", "onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) { // LocationListener
    Log.d("myLogs", "Location.lat = " + arg0.getLatitude() + ", long = "
            + arg0.getLongitude());
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" >
    </meta-data>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает разрешений на определение примерного местоположения. Добавьте в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не изменилось.